# Dell PowerEdgeServer Case Key Missing

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I just got a Dell PowerEdge T330, but a key is needed to open the side panel. I can't find any key in the packaging. Should I contact Dell?

Comment: I don't meant to be flippant, but this seems like an obvious 'yes.'  Locksmiths and brute force don't seem prudent with new hardware, and I don't think you'll get an answer here that for some reason you won't need access.

Comment: If you bought a car and didn't have a key for the trunk would you call the dealer or post your question on the internet? Common sense would tell you to call the dealer.

Comment: No, you should contact HP.  Tell them you're very dissatisfied with the latest Dell you purchased and want to know if they'll give you a discount on their gear for customer service reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should contact the vendor, in this case Dell, when components are missing or non-functional.